# Mounting non-rack applications in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rack, rails-routing, rails-engines

Let's say I have 2 web applications:

1) One is a regular Rails app

2) The other, is an intranet app (non-ruby app) only accessible through the web server on port 3333 for instance.

Instead of having to go the server and access it: `http://intranet:3333` I want to access expose the intranet app through a rails path. e.g. `http://railsapp.com/otherapp`. Similar to what we can do with you can do with Rails Engines.

Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: only thing I can think of is creating a new action in one of your controllers, setting up the route to match to `http://railsapp.com/otherapp` and in the view for that action, embedding an iframe pointing to `http://intranet:3333`.

Comment: use an nginx to proxy-pass that route to your intranet

Comment: I can't use Nginx as a proxy for this because the routes are dynamic ports might change.